# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error even Naming is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, servlets, foreach

This is my servlet

```
jsonObject.add("MessageInfo", jsonElement);
out.print(jsonObject);
```

and this is my javacript file

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "GetConversation",
    response : "json",
    data : "rideID="+rideID,
    // if received a response from the server
    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(data.MessageInfo);
            $.each(data.MessageInfo, function(index, value) {
                console.log("Data Found");
                var eachrow = "<div class='conversation'>"
                    +"<div class='bubble'>"
                    +value.messageBody
                    +"<div class='pic'>" 
                    +"</div>"; 
                $('.messageContainer').prepend(eachrow);
            }); 
    },
    // If there was no resonse from the server
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // alert("Something really bad happened " + textStatus);
    }
});
```

I am sending a AJAX request to my servlet and receiving response, but when I parse it to my jsp page using $.each loop I am getting this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error

Here is a screenshot of response as well.

[image]

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: can you give value of console.log(data.MessageInfo);

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:13
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:875:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:808:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate

Comment: @AnoopLL
it gives Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used wrong option to [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) it doesn't have `response` option. But you should replace it with `dataType: "json"`. Jquery won't convert a string to JSON object until you use this option.

> `dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))`
>  Type: `String`
>  The type of data that you're expecting
>   back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer
>   it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield
>   XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will
>   execute the script, **and anything else will be returned as a string**).