# Unable to parse JSON data to jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp

This is my servlet

```
jsonObject.add("MessageInfo", jsonElement);
    out.print(jsonObject);
```

and this is my javacript file

```
$.ajax({
type : "POST",
url : "GetConversation",
response : "json",
data : "rideID="+rideID,
// if received a response from the server
success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("success");
    console.log(data.MessageInfo);
        $.each(data.MessageInfo, function(index, value) {
            console.log("Data Found");
            var eachrow = "<div class='conversation'>"
                +"<div class='bubble'>"
                +value.messageBody
                +"<div class='pic'>" 
                +"</div>"; 
            $('.messageContainer').prepend(eachrow);
        }); 
},
// If there was no resonse from the server
error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // alert("Something really bad happened " + textStatus);
}
```

});

I am sending a AJAX request to my servlet and receiving response, but when I parse it to my jsp page using $.each loop I am getting this error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error

Here is a screenshot of response as well.

[image]

Comment: Each function goes far and never comebacks. Post the actual code.

Comment: @RomanC here is the full quoestion and CODe.|
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35408790/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-error-even-naming

Comment: i cant see any myresponseobj in your data

Comment: @RomanC  i am trying it for last 3 hours still no solution kindly suggest me

Comment: @Anoop LL i asked this question before as well
here is the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35408790/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-error-even-naming

Comment: Using `$.each` to loop what? Question is not very concise

Comment: @charlietfl here is my full quoestion
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35408790/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-error-even-naming

Comment: But this question should be self contained. We shouldn't have to go filter through another question to figure this one out. Please update this question with proper details

Comment: @charlietfl this is my question only i posted it few hours back ,,but no one took interest in it.Help Plzz

Comment: That doesn't excuse not including proper detail in this question. Also as others have pointed out your are looking for a property that doesn't exist

Comment: oky let me put all details in it

Comment: because what you get is in an array try something like console.log(data[0].myresponseobj);

Answer (score 0):

The property *myresponseobj* does not exists in your *data* object.
You should try

```
console.log(data.conversation)
```

Comment: Note that logging a property which doesn't exist in this manner doesn't error, it just returns undefined: https://jsfiddle.net/3o9m1owe/